# How do I provide/trigger the special support for letters in AUCTeX?

Tags: emacs, auctex, letters

As you probably know, the `letter` document class has quite a few pieces of metadata that go along with it, e.g. `name`, `address`, `signature`, etc.  It would be really nice if all of this was put into the document when I `C-c C-e RET letter RET RET` (create a skeleton `letter` document).

Currently, the above command produces

```
\documentclass{letter}

\begin{document}
?
\end{document}
```

where `?` is the cursor position.

---

This support already *seems* to be in place via `.../auctex-<ver,11.86>/style/letter.el`, but I don't know how to trigger it.  A search of AUCTeX manual for `letter` doesn't turn up anything useful, either (at least not that I could find).

How can I trigger this functionality (maybe hooking it onto the command above which *seems* appropriate)?

`TeX-add-style` doesn't have very good documentation.  (It is used in `letter.el`.)

Comment: Have you put
`(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)`
in your `.emacs`, as suggested in the first lines of the manual?

Comment: @giordano, you know, they were commented out for some reason.  I uncommented them, reloaded LaTeX-mode, and tried again; no effect.

Comment: @SeanAllread, now you should be able to insert `letter` environment using `C-c C-e letter RET` with autocompletion.

Comment: @giordano I literally *just* tried that.  Make that into an answer and I'll accept it.  :)

Comment: @giordano Actually, this doesn't work *quite* as I need/want it to, but it definitely triggers the support.  If you can figure out a way to hook this onto the above where `documentclass` is `letter`, that would be ideal.

Comment: just to understand your situation, after `C-c C-e letter RET` are you prompted for "sender", "sender address", "recipient", etc? It should work so.

Comment: @giordano yep yep -- the ideal situation would be to trigger `(LaTeX-environment "letter")` upon creating a document with the `letter` class.

Comment: ah, now I understand what you want. In development version of AUCTeX, when you chose `letter` class, the `letter` environment is the default environment after inserting the `document` one (instead of `itemize` or whatever is the value of the variable `LaTeX-default-environment`).  But I suppose it's still not what you desire `:-)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot envisage a way to do exactly what you request without changing some AUCTeX internal functions.  The following is a workaround but it's faster than what you've requested, you only need a single key binding to enter the letter template `:-)`. Add this to your `.emacs`

```
(defun mg-LaTeX-new-letter ()
  "Start a new letter document"
  (interactive)
  (insert "\\documentclass{letter}\n\n")
  (LaTeX-insert-environment "document")
  (TeX-run-style-hooks "letter")
  (LaTeX-env-recipient "letter"))
;; Key binding, comment if you don't want it
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map "\C-cl" 'mg-LaTeX-new-letter)
```

You can insert the whole letter template with <kbd>C-c l</kbd> (of course you can change the key binding) or `M-x mg-LaTeX-new-letter`.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it, the support is triggered by using `C-c C-e letter` (works even in a new document).  But, for some reason, `letter` is not included in the autocomplete list.